# How can I run a Python project on another computer without installing anything on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, virtualenv

I have a Python Project that has a bunch of dependencies (in my VirtualEnv). I need to run my project in my school computer for Demonstration. My School computer does not have python installed, and lets assume also wont have an Internet connection to install it. I have written the program in Windows 10, and the school computer runs Windows 7.

I have looked at these solutions so far, and also here is why I think they may not work.

1. Copy and pasting my virtual Env - Doesnt work because venv's have their own structures and has my username in its paths which it will look for in the other system.
2. Using Py2Exe. I have an Exe file, that I can now run on other systems running Windows 10 without them having python or any of my packages. But I am not sure the VC++ dependencies will be present in windows 7. It may also have some other weird issue that I cant risk.
3. Docker. I am not familiar with Docker, but can do it if this happens to be the only way.

How can I run the python file in that computer?

Also note that I will not have the time to mess around in the other system. Ideally I must plug in my USB and Open the file to run it. If you think there isn't a solution to this, please let me know by telling so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two options.

1. Use an online IDE and Python Interpreter (assuming you did not have internet for downloading Python, but do have internet in general). I suggest [replit](https://replit.com/languages/python3).
2. Use a portable version of Python. Those are available in the [official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-392/) and are called "Windows embeddable package". You can test downloading it to a usb, and running it in some computer without Python; it should work.

Comment: how am I supposed to install libraries in that version of python? It runs, but doesnt when I tried installing pip on it.

Comment: It can't be done with pip. Install the modules in your pc, and add them to the embedded version. Go to your PCPythonPath\Lib\site-packages and copy the one you need. Then go to the embedded, create the Lib folder in PortablePythonPath and copy/paste the modules there. Then add Lib to the file PortablePythonPath\pythonXX._pth. If this solves your issue, please mark as solved.

Comment: `python38.zip/n
./n
Lib/n
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically/n
#import site`
is my _pth file and the Lib folder is in the same directory as this file, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Does it work? Probably should be in a newline. Google it, there are multiple SO posts about this.

Comment: I have added new lines but it doesnt work. Ill try googling

Comment: Yes it finally works, I do have more erros tho, Tkinter does not work when I copy it, but I suppose this is unrelated to the current issue. The key was to installing the exact version of additional libraries in your exact same base python version, and then copy pasting them into embedded Lib path.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PyInstaller to generate an exe file from your code. It runs without installation.

Or you have a look at the [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/)  distribution which is portable and comes with several tools and packages pre-installed.

Note that **Windows 7 only supports Python up to version 3.8**. 3.9 is only supported on Windows 10 and will silently fail to run without giving you any hint.

Comment: I installed Winpython, but cant seem to install additional modules in it. The methods given in winpythons documentation dont seem to work either. How do I install packages on it?

Comment: I normally create a new venv and then just use `pip install` inside the venv

Answer (score 2):

This is how I cloned a Windows Python project from a source machine to a target machine without internet connection where Python isn't installed.

Thanks to conda-pack tool (https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/).

### On the source machine

Install Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual).

Then from Anaconda prompt type the following commands.

```
conda activate
conda update -c defaults conda
conda install conda-pack
conda create -n <my_env_name> python=<python_version_number>
conda activate <my_env_name>
# if using Python Windows extensions:
conda install pywin32
```

Now install the packages you need for your Python project using conda or pip (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).
For instance "conda install <package_name>" or "pip install <package_name>".

And finally export everything to a zip file:

```
# Pack Python environment my_env_name into my_env.zip
conda pack -n <my_env_name> -o my_env.zip
```

### On the target machine

The OS of the source machine must match the OS of the target. This means that environments built on Windows can’t be relocated to Linux.

Unpack my_env.zip and then execute the following commands from Command Prompt.

```
call Scripts\activate.bat
conda-unpack
# At this point the Python environment is exactly as if you installed it here directly
```

Comment: Seems like a cool way to do it, but 1. Does it work if you change from win11 to win7, or win10. 2. Does it work with pip only? 3. do i need to install anaconda on the target

Answer (score 1):

Try python as a portable version.

- Download the python Windows embeddable package(zip package) and extract it to your flash drive.
  https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- In extracted python folder, press the shift key + right click and select open command window(windows 7) / open powershell window here(windows 10) option.
- Type './python' and hit the enter key.

Comment: How do I install modules in this embedded package? I have tried but cant find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Convert that python file to a .exe file using auto-py-to-exe. This would convert your .py to a .exe file which you can run anywhere.

To use auto-py-to-exe, just execute the following command on terminal pip install auto-py-to-exe.

Now on the terminal write auto-py-to-exe and press enter. Select the python file you wanna execute anywhere and click on Convert .py to .exe and you would get the folder containing the .exe file. Transfer this folder to any computer and just by clicking the .exe file that is there inside the folder, the program would start executing normally no matter if the computer does not have python or pycharm installed.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://colab.research.google.com. It will work on any computer, but some codes can't be submitted there.

Comment: But it needs internet connection on the other computer for running the code, which wont be available.