# Issues calling a Python script from VBA in an automated Excel Doc

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation, exe

Trying to run a Python program through an Excel sheet that is apart of my automated processes.

Below is the code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objShell As Object

PythonExe = "C:\Python3\python.exe "
PythonScript = """W:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.py"""
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

When running on my computer, this works. However, my this does not work on my coworkers computer that this will be run on. Some of the libraries I have downloaded and import in this .py are not present on her machine, leading to errors. Is there any way around this? Maybe calling a .exe from VBA would work but I haven't had any luck.

The short answer would be to install the packages on the other computer but this is not efficient in the case of anybody else needing to run the sequence of programs.

Comment: You have to install python and ALL of the libs used in the script on the other machine also

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to avoid this somehow. There is currently one person running it, but if they are out, then it could be a number of people. Python is installed on every computer so it would only be the libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821573/how-can-i-run-a-python-project-on-another-computer-without-installing-anything-o

Comment: Or consider re-writing the functionality in VBA if it's not too complex.